# How I get Azure Data Table ETag value from Razor Page

Tags: c#, azure, razor, razor-pages, azure-table-storage

I use Azure.Data.Table NuGet package for Azure Table Storage. I want to get the ETag property from Razor Page. It comes to the controller as {}.

Example codes are as follows.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(Product product)
    {
        await _tableStorageService.UpdateAsync(product, product.ETag);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

[image]

and cshtml

```
@model AzureStorage.Library.Models.Product
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Add or Update Product</h2>
<form asp-action="@(ViewBag.IsUpdate ? "Update" : "Create")" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div class="form-group mb-2 d-flex" style="column-gap:10px;">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="RowKey" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="PartitionKey" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ETag" />
    
        <input class="form-control mr-1" asp-for="Name" placeholder="Product Name" />
        <input class="form-control mr-1" asp-for="Price" placeholder="Product Price" />
        <input class="form-control mr-1" asp-for="Stock" placeholder="Product Stock" />

        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="@(ViewBag.IsUpdate ? "Update Product" : "Add Product")" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How do I get the ETag value?

Comment: Please share your code as `Code block`, Instead of Images.

Comment: Thank you, I added the image because I want to show the ETag value. I arranged.

Comment: Is the ETag populated properly when you read the table and is it getting written to the hidden field correctly?  What if you expand the property in debug where it shows {} as the value?

Comment: Yes. ETag value correctly written table and hidden input field. ETag value is as in the screenshot ( https://prnt.sc/rAe4XejgEgZh )

Answer (score 1):

*We can fetch the value of E-tag from the properties of the blob.*

*create a storage and container in azure as shown below.*

[image]

*Fetching the E-tag value using C# code.*

[image]

[image]

```
string storageAccount_connectionString ="Connection String";
CloudStorageAccount storage_Account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blob_Client = storage_Account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = 
blob_Client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudBlockBlob block_Blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
block_Blob.UploadText("Sample Text...");

string originalETag = block_Blob.Properties.ETag;
Console.WriteLine("ETag = {0}", originalETag);
```

Comment: Thank you but actually, I get the ETag value from azure and send it to the front side. When I check, the ETag value is coming correctly to the front side, but when I get it from the front side to the controller, the ETag value does not come.

Comment: The fetched ETag value has to be assigned to the property of the class and has to be used based on requirement.